# directionalLight Properties have no visible output

Tags: javascript, three.js

In this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gsnhx/), when i change the following parameters i do not see any visible change(s)

```
directionalLight.shadowCameraVisible = true;
directionalLight.shadowCameraLeft = 1000;
directionalLight.shadowCameraRight = 1000;
directionalLight.shadowCameraBottom = 1000;
directionalLight.shadowCameraTop = 1000;
```

Are there any hidden setting(s)? What is functionality of these parameters.

[Documentation](http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/docs/53/#Reference/Lights/DirectionalLight) does not help either, Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those parameters affect only orthographic camera. So you need to set your camera to `THREE.OrthographicCamera()`. Here is some tutorial on how to use shadows: [Casting Shadows](http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2012/01/20/casting-shadows/).

Generally, you don't see any visible changes because you only have one cube on your scene, so there is nothing that you are casting your shadow on. Add some more geometries to your scene and see how you can settle things based on this tutorial.

Hope that helps!